# How do you make a death counter in minecraft nintendo switch edition

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've tried many different commands to make a death scoreboard but nothing has actually worked. I've tried `/scoreboard objectives add Deaths deathCount` but that doesn't work. How do I add a death counter?

Answer (score 0):

As seen on [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Criteria), the only scoreboard criterion available in BE is `dummy`; `deathCount` is not available. I do not know any way to create a scoreboard that tracks the number of deaths in BE.